# options single use value from json - Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have data coming in from another view model and I'm displaying it in a dropdown menu. I need each option from the other view model to be unique per line, so once the user adds an item to the list, that option isn't available anymore.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QTUqD/9/

```
    window.usrViewModel = new function () {
    var self = this;
    window.viewModel = self;

    self.list = ko.observableArray();
    self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
    self.pageIndex = ko.observable(0);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();    
    self.extData = ko.observableArray();    
    extData = ExtListViewModel.list();


    self.edit = function (item) {
        if($('#usrForm').valid()) {
        self.selectedItem(item);
        }
    };

    self.cancel = function () {
        self.selectedItem(null);
    };

    self.add = function () {
        if($('#usrForm').valid()) {
        var newItem = new Users();
        self.list.push(newItem);
        self.selectedItem(newItem);
        self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
        };
    };
    self.remove = function (item) {

            if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) {

                    self.list.remove(item);
                    if (self.pageIndex() > self.maxPageIndex()) {
                        self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
                    }

            }
            $('.error').hide();

    };
    self.save = function () {

        self.selectedItem(null);

    };

    self.templateToUse = function (item) {
        return self.selectedItem() === item ? 'editUsrs' : 'usrItems';
    };

    self.pagedList = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var size = self.pageSize();
        var start = self.pageIndex() * size;
        return self.list.slice(start, start + size);
    });
    self.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return Math.ceil(self.list().length / self.pageSize()) - 1;
    });
    self.previousPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() > 0) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() - 1);
        }
    };
    self.nextPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() < self.maxPageIndex()) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() + 1);
        }
    };
    self.allPages = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var pages = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= self.maxPageIndex() ; i++) {
            pages.push({ pageNumber: (i + 1) });
        }
        return pages;
    });
    self.moveToPage = function (index) {
        self.pageIndex(index);
    };

};

ko.applyBindings(usrViewModel, document.getElementById('usrForm'));

function Users(fname, lname, email, phone, access, usrExtVal){
    this.fname = ko.observable(fname);
    this.lname = ko.observable(lname);
    this.email = ko.observable(email);
    this.phone = ko.observable(phone);
    this.access = ko.observable(access);
    this.usrExtVal = ko.observableArray(usrExtVal);   
}
```

---

```
<form id="usrForm">
<h2>Users</h2>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Access</th>
            <th>Extension</th>
            <th style="width: 100px; text-align:right;" />
        </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody data-bind=" template:{name:templateToUse, foreach: pagedList }"></tbody>
</table>
<p class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.add" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Users</a></p>
<div class="pagination pull-left">
    <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === 0 }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: previousPage">Previous</a></li></ul>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: allPages">
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.pageNumber === ($root.pageIndex() + 1) }"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.pageNumber, click: function() { $root.moveToPage($data.pageNumber-1); }"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === maxPageIndex() }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: nextPage">Next</a></li></ul>
</div>

<br clear="all" />
    <script id="usrItems" type="text/html">
   <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: fname"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lname"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: access"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: usrExtVal"></td>
        <td class="buttons">
            <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

 <script id="editUsrs" type="text/html">
   <tr>
        <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="fname" data-bind="value: fname" /></td>
        <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="lname" data-bind="value: lname" /></td>
        <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="email" data-bind="value: email" /></td>
        <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="phone" data-bind="value: phone" /></td>
        <td><select data-bind="value: access"><option>Employee</option><option>Administrator</option><option>PBX Admin</option><option>Billing</option></select></td>
        <td><select data-bind="options: $root.extOptions, optionsText: 'extension', value: usrExtVal"></select></td>
        <td class="buttons">
            <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.save" href="#" title="save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
        </td>
   </tr>
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is a fiddle that computes the available values based on the those already in use:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/QTUqD/11/

--

HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.availableExtData, optionsText: 'extension', value: usrExtVal"></select>
```

JS

```
self.availableExtData = ko.computed(function() {
    var inUse = [];
    if (!self.selectedItem()) return inUse;

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.list(), function(item) {
        if (inUse.indexOf(item.usrExtVal().extension) == -1 && self.selectedItem() != item) inUse.push(item.usrExtVal().extension);
    });

    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.extData(), function(item) {
        return inUse.indexOf(item.extension) == -1;
    });
});
```

--

The code ensures that when the select item is being edited that it's current value is available.  Additionally I also don't show the add button once there is a row for all available values.

Answer (score 0):

Make a computed observable with the available options, that filters away from the complete list (*extData*) those that have already been assigned to an item - except the one used by the selected item - and then bind the options of the select field to that computed instead of the full list.